# My page is loading several times

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website is loading 3 times every time I go to
website/user/slug.

This is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpg|gif)$

#redirect to index.php?url=slug
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Anyone can give me a hint on how to solve this multiple loading?

Comment: don't think there's anything in those rules that's causing your page to load 3 times

Comment: Strange thing ! I'm not seeing any reason on my code to this happen.
Does anyone has a sugestion of why this might happen?

Comment: The only possibility is that your PHP code (perhaps a framework) is performing some kind of redirect. As we can't see your code (perhaps a User controller), we can't give detailed help. There could also be something in your JS files - take a look at those too, if you are not sure.

Comment: The page is huge, that being the only reason I didn't post the code !
But actually you might be on the right track !

I'm triple checking all the included files right now. I'll keep you updated since I've seen this asked once in a while but never trully solved herer on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

So, This is not a complete answer but I'm updating this until I get the full answer.

As suposed on one of the answers, I'm using my own framework, it works by looking at the url and including the view in index.php as all the components necessary to this page.

So, as said the page was loading 3 times ( or making 3 entries on the database ), and I've stated digging my loading function, on wich I found a script that when a user is not activated it redirects to the home page. This header(location blah) was making the page load one extra time.

I've changed it to include home view and by now the page is only loading twice.

As far as I'm concerned I don't have any other redirect on the php scripts. I'll triple check but if not, I have to update this answer.

***UPDATE ->*** at this point I'm having a strange situation here. I've run all my php and javascript code, and they are clean. I've finnaly discovered the bit of code that is giving me this problem, although it's a strange situation:

It seems that the bootstrap modal is giving me a redirect and I don't now why. I just have the html code at this point so I'm checking for javascript code on it and afterwards I'll look at bootstrap.js in order to find why this is happening.

I'll keep this thread updated !

***UPDATE->*** OK ! Now I have the full answer, it seems it wasn't bootstrap but an image I had. So I had this image called blahh that it's purpose was to preview an uploaded image, so, since the image didn't have a url defined, the it was redirecting ( the explanation is something like this lol ! I'm not even quite sure of what's happening here but giving the image an url I stopped having this error ).